# Not letting button and div go into each other when shrinking the website

Tags: html, css, responsive

I tried to research it a lot but couldn't find anything useful:

My website is build that there is a box right in the middle and under it is a button. I noticed that if i shrink the websites height, the button goes under the box. How can i make it responsive? Thank you a lot in advance and sorry if there is already a question like that.

```css
.bg-text {
  border: 3px inset #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  }

.btn {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 38%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div class="bg-text">

    <h1>h1</h1>
    <p>p</p>

 </div>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">About</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we go:

```
.bg-text {
border: 3px inset #f1f1f1;

margin: 20px auto;
z-index: 2;
width: 80%;
padding: 20px;

text-align: center;
}

.btn {  

display: block;

margin: 0 auto;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why

Comment: i removed absolute because its always at the same spot, now the boxes are relative, i added "margin: 20px auto" that means it createds a 20px gap on the top and bottom and center the box in the middle. i did the same to the "btn". first i say to display it as a block then i center it with "margin: 0 auto;"